# Making tree from array representation with option to choose root

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree

I have tree in array like this:

```
[ {val: 10,index: 0},{val: 20,index: 1},{val: 30,index: 2},{val: 40,index: 5} ]
```

and i making tree using indexes ( 0 is root) and my result is this:

```
   50                     
     \
20    30
 \    /
   10
```

indexes: ( Now i hope understand this :) )

```
  3   4   5    6               
   \ /     \  /
    1       2
     \    /
       0
```

Now I have problem with getting tree through index from my api

When i attempt tree/0 it is okay, return this tree above but when i attempt  tree/1
i only want

```
20
```

or tree/2

```
   50
     \
     30
```

Is there any alogrithm which help me exclude unnecessary branches? Any ideas?

Best regards

Comment: what is the relation between an index and the orientation of the tree ?

Comment: from where 50 came ? what is the relationship between each nodes of this tree?

Comment: 0 is root then 1 is left , 2 is right, 3 is left of 1 etc

Comment: Your array has no tree structure info.  eg. index 2 has value 30, but nothing else.. There is no tree pointers anywhere, what you would normally do is say give give the children a parent index.  eg. tree item 50 would have a parent index to tree item 30. etc.  Rather than an array, an object literal would be a nice container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a flat array without any parent's, you really don't have a tree structure.

But tree structures in Javascript using an Object is very easy.

Below is an example ->

```js
/*
  3   4   5    6               
   \ /     \  /
    1       2
     \    /
       0
*/

var tree = {
  index: 0,
  val: 'Root',
  nodes: [
    {
      index: 1,
      val: 'Value 1',
      nodes: [
        {  
          index: 3,
          val: 'Value 3'
        }, {
          index: 4,
          val: 'Value 4'
        }
      ]
    }, {
      index: 2,
      val: 'Value 2',
      nodes: [
        {  
          index: 5,
          val: 'Value 5'
        }, {
          index: 6,
          val: 'Value 6'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

function display(s) {
  document.write('<div>' + s + '</div>');
}

function find(root, index) {
  if (root.index === index) return root;
  if (root.nodes) {
    for (let l = 0; l < root.nodes.length; l ++) {
      let node = root.nodes[l];
      if (node.index === index) return node;
      node = find(node, index);
      if (node) return node;
    }      
  }
  return null;
}

function treeSize(tree) {
  let size = 0;
  if (tree.nodes)
    for (let l = 0; l < tree.nodes.length; l ++)
      size += treeSize(tree.nodes[l]);
  return size + 1;   
}

function showTree(name, index) {
  let node = find(tree, index);
  if (!node) return;
  display(name + '-> Size: ' + treeSize(node));
  function draw(node, indent) {
    display(indent + node.val);
    if (node.nodes) {
      for (let l = 0; l < node.nodes.length; l ++)
        draw(node.nodes[l], indent + '----');
    }
  }
  draw(node, '');
}

showTree('Tree 0', 0);
display('&nbsp;');
showTree('Tree 2', 2);
```

Comment: Thank you very much bro, can you help me in change this to return json object? Because it is asynchronous function

Comment: how i catch moment of end recurection function draw() ??

Comment: Not sure what you mean return json object, if you wanted the Json value of say id 2,  you could do  `var json = JSON.stringify(find(tree,2));`  if that's what you mean.

Comment: The showtree is just a function to show the tree inside the snippet,.. The find function is most likely all your after.

Comment: last question, maybe answer is very close, how to count quickly size of tree?

Answer (score 1):

If you define your tree in the following way,

children of index i = 2*i+1 and 2*i+2

then you can perform a depth first search to print the branches resulting from an index until it reaches the leaf, so

```
DFS(1) -> DFS(3)
```

you would get 50 and 30

```
DFS(i) // would call
DFS(2*i+1) and DFS(2*i+2)
```